# Save Machine State automatically when Host is hibernated

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

My settings are:

```
Windows 10 HOST 64bit
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit as a VM
VirtualBox 5.2.12
```

I used a lot the hibernation mode for Windows 10 at work. While rebooting, my VM is freezed and I'm always unable to wake it up. Knowing that VirtualBox doesn't support hibernation, is there any way to save machine state (which is really close, ideally, to the concept of "hibernation") automatically when the host is hibernated?

Comment: You can do this via calling `shutdown /h` in a wrapper script (python, bash via cygwin, etc.), however your guests should just return after wake-up of the host... just like any other program.

Comment: @TNierath last statement is false. Is a known "won't fix" bug of VirtualBox.

Comment: I'm running an Ubuntu Server guest on my laptop and nonstop hibernate my Win 10 host. No problem.

Comment: So is somekind of bug?

Comment: From the perspective of the host, VMs are just another process, taking up some amount of RAM, which will be saved and restored by hibernation. Of course, the guests will not know what has happened, like every other process, they will just continue execution on wake-up (of the host). I never had VMs crash on me upon waking up from hibernation.